# Appending new element to div, jQuery stops working for new element

Tags: jquery

Okay, so I know the question was worded confusingly but here's what's happening. I have a 'post' element, which is repeated throughout the page that is set up like this:

```
          <div class="post-basic" id="post-{unique id}">
            <div class="title-card">
              <div class="avatar-sec">
                <img src="{link to avatar}" class="avatar" ref="Avatar" />
              </div>
              <div class="name-card">
                <span class="display-name">{display name}</span>
                <span class="handle">@{handle}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="action">
                <div class="follow-button {filled with either: follow or followed}" id="{unique id}">
                  {filled with either: follow or followed}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and my jQuery is set up so that when you click the div.follow-button it'll change to 'followed' and send a POST to php page. Set up like so:

```
$('.follow-button').click(
  function() {
    var user_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var follow_url = "./func/follow.func.php";
    if ($(this).hasClass("follow")) {
      $(this).removeClass('follow').addClass('followed').text('followed');
      $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: follow_url,
             data: {id:user_id}, // serializes the form's elements.
             success: function(data)
             {
              $('#'+user_id).parents('.post-basic').remove();
              $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "./func/gather.basic.func.php",
                     data: {}, // serializes the form's elements.
                     success: function(data)
                     {   
                      var response = $.parseJSON(data);
                      $('.posts').append('<div class="post-basic" id="post-'+ response[0].streamID_gather +'"><div class="title-card"><div class="avatar-sec"><img src="'+ response[0].avatarSrc +'" class="avatar" ref="Avatar"/></div><div class="name-card"><span class="display-name">'+ response[0].display_name +'</span><span class="handle">@'+ response[0].name +' '+ response[0].followsYou +'</span></div><div class="action"><div class="follow-button '+ response[0].follow +'"id="'+ response[0].streamID_gather +'">'+ response[0].follow +'</div></div></div></div>');
                      }
                   });
              }
           });
      }
  }
);
```

I am just getting started with jQuery so I'm sure there's plenty of other ways to do this same thing but essentially: when `div.follow-button` is clicked, the text inside the `div` changes to followed and the `class` is changed to `followed`. Then, sends a `POST` request to `"./func/follow.func.php";` which it does. If the request successfully processes, it'll send another request to `"./func/gather.func.basic.php";` which returns a `json` array. With the array, the `jQuery` will then append to the container `div.posts` a new `post` like the others with the responded data. Which it does. Everything said above works and it's all good. But, when I try and click the follow button with the new `div.post` it does not work. Is it because the jQuery is already loaded or what?

Comment: appears you want to do something on completion of an ajax call - nesting another ajax call looks "odd" here, just do them both on one?  Or use promises perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323

Comment: Note you may want to hook the event on the container that contains everything.

Comment: where are you binding `onclick` to the new follow button create after clicking the first `follow` button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of the OP I believe this is an issue about how event listeners work in javascript.

When you do:

```
$('.follow-button').click(handlerFunction);
```

It is binding an event to **ONLY** the current matching items in the DOM.

If you're adding & removing elements that you want to respond to the same event handler you have 2 options:

1) update event handlers after inserting new content into the DOM... e.g. you need to call `$(selector).on('click', handlerFunction)` again

**OR... a much better solution**

2) attach the event to a **parent element** that is not changing in the DOM... e.g.

```
$('body').on('click', '.follow-button', handlerFunction);
```

Attached an event listener to the **body** of the HTML, but it will only fire the event if the "clicked" item matched the selector...

Also **you probably want to put this on a more specific parent element, rather than body**. I don't know you're page structure so figured this was an easy example.

Comment: Thank you very much, explained it perfectly.